Странное поведение функции ФИЛЬТР.XML в Excel
С помощью браузера я отправляю запрос https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/boards/TQBR/securities.xml?iss.meta=off&iss.only=marketdata&marketdata.columns=SECID,LAST и получаю ответ
***
<row SECID="AMEZ" LAST="73.08"/>
<row SECID="APTK" LAST="11.38"/>
<row SECID="AQUA" LAST="770.5"/>
***

Мне необходимо из строки
<row SECID="APTK" LAST="11.38"/>

достать LAST, то есть цифру 11.38.
Я сделал следующую формулу в Эксель 2013:
=ФИЛЬТР.XML(ВЕБСЛУЖБА("https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/boards/TQBR/securities.xml?iss.meta=off&iss.only=marketdata&marketdata.columns=SECID,LAST");"//document//data//rows//row[@SECID='APTK']/@LAST")

и получаю результат 14185
Я сделал отдельно получение xml, и с ним все в порядке, так что проблема именно в формуле ФИЛЬТР.XML.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать?

Проблема не воспроизводится на Excel 2019 - формула правильно выдает сейчас 11.324, в исходнике <row SECID="APTK" LAST="11.324"/>
